# Reloading a dictionary from database without resetting IIS

Tags: c#, sql, dictionary

We use a dictionary in a web service.  The dictionary is loaded from a database table.  How can I refresh the dictionary every time the database table is changed without resetting IIS and using SQLDependency?

Answer (score 0):

You might use some kind of publisher-subscriber implementation to notify your app or service that it must re-load that dictionary.

Whenever some part of your code changes the database it should produce a notification and subscribers (for example, *the dictionary*) can react to database changes.

Note your database won't emit these notifications but you'll be sending these in your actual C# code where you perform a write transaction agains your database.

At the end of the day it's something like this pseudo-code:

```
// Send a notification
pubsub.Notify();

pubsub.Subscribe
(
     () =>
     {
          // Do stuff here if I receive a notification
     }
);
```

You can use a message queue like MSMQ, RabbitMQ or even Redis pub-sub to solve your issue with less effort!

Comment: Thanks Matias. The problem is that my application is not the one changing the database but it reads the data and performs tasks based on the values from the database.  Here is a basic workflow:
1. Database is updated with values by users (running SPs)
2. Application should get the updated value and use the data to determine what task to perform